# Monitor status of pouchdb replicate

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

If the user loses Internet or the server goes offline, how can I notifiy the user that live sync stopped?

```
    var localdb = new PouchDB('localdb')
    var remotedb = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/xyz');
    localdb.replicate.to(remotedb, {live: true});
    localdb.replicate.from(remotedb, {live: true});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this on IRC, but in case anyone's curious, `db.replicate(...).on('error')` seemed to be the missing key.